# Lie Algebra of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ and $\mathrm{O}(2)$ are the SAME - why?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a Lie Group (with identity element of $e$), then my definition of the Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ is the tangent space of $G$ at $e$, so that $\mathfrak{g} = T_{e}G$.

The Lie Algebra of $both$ $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ and $\mathrm{O}(2)$ is given by:

$T_{e}\mathrm{O}(2) = T_{e}\mathrm{SO}(2) = \{ \ A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})\ |\ A^{T} = - A \ \}$

My question is, WHY are they the same? My thinking is that since:

$\mathrm{O}(2) = \mathrm{SO}(2) \cup \{ \ A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})\ |\ A^{T}A = I\  \mathrm{and}\ \det(A) = -1 \ \}$

Which means that $\mathrm{O}(2)$ is disconnected. Since one of its constituent disconnected sets is $\mathrm{SO}(2)$, then it must have the same Lie Algebra as this set? Is this kind of thinking correct? I am not sure if I have articulated myself properly.

Comment: You are essentially right. I woukd add the observation that SO(2) is the connected component that contains the identity. The Lie algebra of a Lie group only "sees" things that are connected to the identity.

Comment: Yes. $SO(2)$ is the connected component of the identity in $O(2)$, and the Lie algebra only sees things going on in arbitrarily small neighborhoods of the identity.